# Get json in angular acording to url params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mongodb

I want to get json in angular from mongoDB.
I have server side that sent to my client side json acording to "idstud" and I want that my client side display it to the screen with angular.

this is my server side (controller):

```
exports.getDataById = function(req,res){
    var idStud1=req.params.id;
    User.find({idstud : idStud1},function(err,user){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(user);
        });
}
```

my server side (index.js):

```
app.get('/studentsById/:idstud',student.getDataById);
```

my client side (controller):
var showStudentById = angular.module('showStudentById',[]);

showStudentById.controller('showStudById',

```
['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
     $http.get("http://localhost:3000/studentsById/:idstud").success(function(data){
        $scope.studentByIdController = data; 
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

my client side html:

```
<html ng-app="showStudentById">
 <head>
 <title>student</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="showStudById">
 <tbody>
 <div>
 <h1 class="text-center">All Students By Id</h1>
 <div ng-repeat="student in studentByIdController">
     <h2 class="text-center">name:{{student.name}}</h2>
     <h2 class="text-center">id:{{student.idstud}}</h2>
     <h2 class="text-center">grade:{{student.grade}}</h2>
     <h2 class="text-center">year:{{student.year}}</h2>
     <h2 class="text-center">coures:{{student.coures}}</h2>
     <h2 class="text-center">--------------------------</h2>
 </div>
.....
```

Comment: try $scope.studentByIdController = data.data;

Comment: not working its return me empty array,not a json

Comment: What's your problem??? you want to know how to fill "idstud" in angular controller from browser url or what?

Comment: What's the output from your `console.log(data)`?

Comment: nathing in the console

Comment: my problen is that I get the json from server by id that I put in the url but in the client side I get all json and not according to specific id. how can I print to the sreen the json according to the id that I get him? MeTe-30